# Is it possible to port a python library (and underlying libs related to it) from one computer to another?

Tags: python, lib

I installed one python library (camelot) on my mac. Now tried to run the same code on a linux machine where I do not have a root access.

It needs some underlying .so libs to be installed etc. on a machine but I do not have access to install them..

Is there a way to port the whole library as a package to another machine and run it without installation?

Answer (score 1):

This is when **docker** comes in handy because you can encapsulate entire environments and underlying libraries. Python/Conda Environments (pipenv/conda-env) are another way to manage dependencies but are not as easily portable.

Comment: The problem is that I can not even have docker installed there :)